# How to remove ( 0, 0 ) from forum page in bbpress

Tags: buddypress, bbpress

I would like to remove trailing (0, 0) from the /forums page (forums being the 'forums base') in bbpress. The site is also using buddypress and bbpress got installed as a part of 'group forums'.

Here's how the /forums page looks like at the moment:

General Forums

```
General (0, 0),
Methodology (0, 0),
Implementation (0, 0),
Tools (0, 0),
Training (0, 0),
New to Lean and Six Sigma (0, 0),
The Water Cooler (0, 0)
```

Comment: I've never seen this before. Do you have a link?

Comment: I can't share the link as the site is private & under development at the moment. However here's an image that might be helpful - http://i41.tinypic.com/2lv0ar.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, these are produced by the function `bbp_list_forums()`, as called in the template file `bbpress/loop-single-forum.php`. You should be able to copy that template into your theme and change the call to `bbp_list_forums()` as follows:

`<?php bbp_list_forums( array( 'show_topic_count' => false, 'show_reply_count' => false ) ) ?>`

See bbPress's inline docs for `bbp_list_forums()` here: https://bbpress.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/plugin/bbp-includes/bbp-forum-template.php#L667